# Keyboard overlaps bottom button until refreshing screen

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, pull-to-refresh, hybrid

I have the following component: 
a `ScrollView` with a `TextInput` and a `Button`. I want the `TextInput` on the top and the `Button` at the bottom (`justifyContent: 'space-between'`). I'm running this component from an Android Native app. So I'm working on a **hybrid app**.
**The issue:**
When I tap on the `TextInput`, the keyboard appears and it overlaps the bottom `button`. If after that I refresh the `scrollView` by pulling down, the bottom `button` appears over the keyboard (what I want).
Something happens after the **`RefreshControl`** renders, that set the correct position of my `button`. But my component doesn't look like well until I pull to refresh it and the react-native `RefreshControl` component is activated.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, KeyboardAvoidingView, TextInput, RefreshControl, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class Authenticate extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
          refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={this.state.refreshing} />}>
          <View style={{ height: 200, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                height: 60,
                color: 'white',
                backgroundColor: 'gray',
                fontSize: 20,
                textAlign: 'center'
              }}
              value="Press Me"
            />
          </View>
          <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', width: '100%' }} title="Footer button" />
        </ScrollView>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: App]

Comment: you can use the KeyboardListener "keyboardDidShow" and on the callback of that listener animate the footer button to go above the keyboard and then run reverse animation on "keyboardDidHide"

Comment: Maybe try, android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize attribute in your manifest's <activity> element with one of the "adjust" values till you get your keyboard to respond as you like. Source: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#Respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `MD Naseem Ashraf` suggest here , the issue was fixed by adding the following line in my Manifest file `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this if you want to hide button and then it won't come above keyboard.Change your  AndroidManifest.xml file.
    <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" //add this line
                    android:exported="true">
```

Comment: Yes, I have this line on my Manifest. The strange thing is that the button appears correctly only after I refresh the screen by pulling down.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the activity tag in your manifest file

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Yes, I have this line on my Manifest. The strange thing is that the button appears correctly only after I refresh the screen by pulling down.

Answer (score 0):

`<KeyboardAvoidingView>`Replace with `<SafeAreaView>` and give it flex of 1.

Comment: It doesn't change anything. I don't know how `SafeArea` could help here. Also, as the documentation says, it only works on ios.